# Is it possible to apply CSS styles to a dialogue or wizard modal window in Eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse

Is it possible to apply CSS styles to a dialogue or wizard modal window in Eclipse? I've been able to use the CSS Spy plug-in to figure out most elements but when I bring a modal up, Spy becomes inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible for dialogs and wizards that you create. However changing some of the styles of a dialog or wizard can be quite tricky (such as the dialog background). To some extent you can also apply styles to existing dialogs.

For dialogs you create you probably want to set a CSS class for the dialog area to make it easier to specify styles applying just to the dialog:

```java
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent)
{
  Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

  composite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);

  WidgetElement.setCSSClass(composite, "DialogClass");

  ...
```

This sets the CSS class and the composite background mode.

You can also apply styles to any dialog using CSS selectors in the form:

```css
Shell[style~='SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL'] > Composite > Text
{
    font-size: 14pt;  
}
```

which applies the style to a Text control in a application model dialog.

An example `Dialog` with styling:
[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks Greg. Will give this a shot and post results. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to apply CSS to any Dialog, it almost fixed my styling issue today! Do you know if there is any way to specifically target wizards with CSS? I was looking at the composite structure of the wizard dialog to find any named composite I could use but didn't find any. My use case is to apply styles to all the wizards, not only mine.

Comment: @zelus Well wizards are still basically Dialogs (`WizardDialog` to be exact). I do style some wizards in my own code but I haven't tried to style any existing one.

Comment: @greg-449 I agree, they are `WizardDialog`, but I didn't manage to find a way to apply styles to them. The `Shell` selector in your original reply works well, but I can't use `WizardDialog` as a CSS selector since its not part of the composite hierarchy (or at least not obviously, I am maybe missing something but all I see in the hierarchy is a bunch of composites). So my main issue here is that I can't differentiate a wizard from any other modal, they are all shells with a bunch of unnamed composites (assuming I can't add a class to the wizard because it's not my own).

Answer (score -1):

No. The CSS styling feature works on Eclipse 4 workbench model which represents the workbench window along with editors and views within it, but not the content of editors, views or dialogs.

Comment: Not so. It is possible to style everything with CSS in an e4 application - I have several that do so.