# How to exclude dialogue shells from Eclipse CSS Styling?

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to apply a white style across my views and panes and toolbars etc and have therefore put the following in to my E4 stylesheet.

```
Shell {
    background-color: white;
}
```

this works for almost all I wanted to do but with an annoying side effect of changing dialogues to look like this:

[image: Messed up Dialoge]

Firstly i tried to apply styles across all the parts to make it all go white, but I couldn't get the labels to play ball. I tried to do this using [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707822/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-styles-to-a-dialogue-or-wizard-modal-window-in-eclip)

Anyway, I discovered that file dialogues etc can get pretty messed up trying to change everything white so took a new approach, which is just to stop dialogues from going white along with everything else.

Best i could do was this:

```
Shell[style~='SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL'] 
{
   background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

Which works for my current OS theme, but obviously not very portable, any help on how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Glen x

Comment: Best not to style `Shell`, try classes such as `.MTrimmedWindow`. Getting the styles right is just plain hard work!

Comment: Is there any resources that list all these classes and have examples of what the effect, because shell does exactly what i want bar that dialogue issue. I'm trying to change tabs space between tabs main coolbar, etc. MTrimmedWindow didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I don't know of a list, you can look at the CSS that Eclipse itself uses for some ideas. I tend to explicitly set my own class names for everything. There is a CSS Spy tool that may help.